# JavaScript xhr GET method not sending form data to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a problem described as title.

```
<form id="mloginform">
  Manager ID: <input type="text" name="mid" id="mid" > </label>  
  <br/> 
  Password: <input type="text" name="mpwd" id="mpwd"> </label> 
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" name="mlogin" value="login" id="mlogin"/>
</form>
```

Above is the simple form i have.

```
var xhr = createRequest(); // this is in another js.
function checklogin(mid, mpwd) {
    var mid = document.getElementById("mid").value;
    var mpwd = document.getElementById("mpwd").value;
    var moutput = document.getElementById("moutput");

    alert(encodeURIComponent(mid));
    alert(encodeURIComponent(mpwd));

    moutput.innerHTML = "";
    xhr.open("GET", "mlogin.php?mid=" + encodeURIComponent(mid) + "&mpwd=" + encodeURIComponent(mpwd) + "&value=" + Number(new Date), true);
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

Above is the xhr code. two alert did show the input value. but `xhr.open` cant send data to php file (only page refreshed, nothing else); i am pretty sure the problem is located in `xhr.open`, because php works fine if i use following form.

```
<form action="mlogin.php" method="get" id="mloginform">
  Manager ID: <input type="text" name="mid" id="mid" > </label>  
  <br/> 
  Password: <input type="text" name="mpwd" id="mpwd"> </label> 
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" name="mlogin" value="login" id="mlogin"/>
</form>
```

Comment: How have you confirmed that the data isn't being sent to PHP?  There's no PHP code here, and your JavaScript code is ignoring the result of the AJAX request.  Also, "page refreshed" is highly suspect.  If you're using AJAX, why is the page refreshing at all?

Comment: How are you calling checklogin?

Comment: You have no action on Your Form, and you’re not using .preventDefault in your JS to keep the form from submitting normally.

Comment: @CriketX — "You have no action on Your Form" — That action attribute is optional.

Comment: @CriketX — "and you’re not using .preventDefault in your JS to keep the form from submitting normally" — We can't see how the JS function is being called so we can't be sure that is relevent.

Comment: @Quentin if you look at the form that works, it has an action, his new one doesn’t. And he mentioned the page just refreshes..

Comment: Hi all, the problem solved.   I need to return false after calling checklogin, not sure why, but it works.   Thank you all anyway